# Convert a vector of binary numbers into a vector of decimals

Tags: matlab

A (hopefully efficiently) conversion from a binary number `b` into a decimal number `d` is

```
d = sum(b.*2.^(numel(b)-1:-1:0)) + 1
```

How would I efficiently (read: not using a for-loop) convert a vector of binary numbers `bvec`, *e.g.* the three binary numbers in `bvec = logical([0 1;1 0;1 1])` into a vector of decimal numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bin2dec`.

```
>> str = reshape('0001011100110001', 8, [])'

str =

  2×8 char array

    '00010111'
    '00110001'

>> bin2dec(str)

ans =

    23
    49
```

N.B. - Matlab is column-major, so reshaping a string can lead to unexpected results if not done carefully:

```
>> abc = 'abcdefghijklmnop';
>> reshape(abc, [], 8) % does not maintain original order

ans =

  2×8 char array

    'acegikmo'
    'bdfhjlnp'

>> reshape(abc, 8, [])' % maintains original order

ans =

  2×8 char array

    'abcdefgh'
    'ijklmnop'
```